# AH01630: client denied by server configuration for files named dhtxxxx.xxx

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4

I can't figure out why apache is throwing this error, all the files in the document root directory can be accessed but I get a forbidden error when I try to access files named dhtxxxx.xxx, if I change the filename to "htmlxgrid_dhx_terrace.css" it works fine.

The document root dir has the `require all granted` so that's not the problem:

```
<Directory /path/to/document/root >
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here's what I see in the logs:

> [authz_core:error] [pid XXXX:tid XXXXXXX] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:XXXX] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /path/to/document/root/dhtmlxGrid/skins/dhtmlxgrid_dhx_terrace.css
>
> apachectl -v
> Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
> Server built:   Oct 14 2015 14:20:21

Answer (score 5):

I solved this adding

```
Require all granted
```

to my /etc/apache2/site-available/d8.conf

This is a working file for Drupal 8

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName local.d8
    ServerAlias *.local.d8  local.d8.*
    DocumentRoot /home/a/Public/d8
    <Directory /home/a/Public/d8>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/d8_error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/d8_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem, it was this in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

`<Files ~ "^.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>`

It should be:

`<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>`

It turns out to be a bug in the apache2 chef cookbook that was introduced here:
https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/commit/6cb7d794cdf6fe05e650d17e432e5f5a6a86c8ea

Solution was to downgrade apache2 cookbook to 3.0.1.